# disable firebug extension through javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to disable firebug extension icon in popup window.can we hide or remove it in popup window through javascript or php? i searched here and found this code but its not working.

```
if (! ('console' in window) || !('firebug' in console)) {
  var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir','dirxml', 'group','groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];
  window.console = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
      window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modal dialog using div element for popups

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

There is no other way to prevent firebug in popup window. Your code only overrides the console object.